# How to keep metadata fields on one line

Tags: html, css, wordpress, metadata

I am trying to customize the metadata for my posts. Specifically, I want to change the separator from the default forward slash (/) to a vertical line (|). I also want to add the word "Updated" before the date displayed. And, I want to keep the option to display reading time. (*FYI: I know basically nothing about coding, just trying to override the metadata output from Astra)

I used this code to change the separator (found in a post about how to customize post meta in Astra theme):

```css
add_filter('astra_single_post_meta', 'custom_post_meta');
function custom_post_meta($old_meta)
{
 $post_meta = astra_get_option('blog-single-meta');
 if (!$post_meta) return $old_meta;
 
 $new_output = astra_get_post_meta($post_meta, "|");
 if (!$new_output) return $old_meta;
 
 return "<div class='entry-meta'>$new_output</div>";
}
```

See the output in image 1 - looks great!

[output of new code for separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isJqA.png)

This is close, but still needed to add "Updated" before the date.  So, I used this code (from same post mentioned above):

```css
function astra_post_date()
{
 $format = apply_filters('astra_post_date_format', '');
 $published = esc_html(get_the_date($format));
 $modified = esc_html(get_the_modified_date($format));

 $output = '<p class="posted-on">';
 $output .= 'Updated: <span class="published" ';
 $output .= 'itemprop="datePublished">' . $published;
 $output .= '</span>';
 $output .= '</p>';
 
 return apply_filters('astra_post_date', $output);
}
```

See output in image 2 - content is perfect, but formatting is wrong. Can't figure out how to edit the code to get all 3 fields on the same line.

[output of new code for adding "Update"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwvJW.png)

What do I need to change in the 2nd block of code to keep everything on one line like the 1st block of code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show me your live page. I can help.

Comment: https://test.financeoverfifty.com/budget-101/

Comment: You can make use of CSS: `.entry-meta { display: flex; } span.posted-by.vcard.author { margin-left: 5px; }` You can change the selectors based on your preference whether to target single posts or homepage etc. This is what I get applying that CSS: https://nimb.ws/jX158H

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to be very specific with me because I don't know code.  I just copied and pasted your code to the bottom of my theme's functions.php file and this caused my site to have a critical error. Do I have to put it somewhere specific, and/or in a certain format?

Comment: CSS does not belong in functions.php. Try adding it to your `style.css` file. or the Custom CSS function of your theme.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/ Choose what fits your site.